# returning JSON in php

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest

can anyone please tell me how to get json from REST webservice.

my code is as given below

here when we run the application and if give say for example

**localhost/examples/Example.php?method=addInts&n1=3&n2=5**

will gives us the output as

```
{"Result":"3 + 5 = 8"}
```

how how can we expect to return the output as json like

```
[{"Result":8}]
```

my php code

```
<?php

  require_once "../Rest.php";

  class Hello
  {
     // example: http://path/to/examples/Example.php?method=sayHello&name=World
     public static function sayHello($name)
     {
        return array("Response" => "Hello, " . $name);
     }

     // example: http://path/to/examples/Example.php?method=addInts&n1=3&n2=5
     public static function addInts($n1, $n2)
     {
        if (is_numeric($n1) && is_numeric($n2))
        {
          return array("Result" => "$n1 + $n2 = " . (string)($n1 + $n2));
        }
        else
        {
          return array("Error" => "Parameters must be numeric.");
        }
     }
  }

  $rest = new Server(Hello);
  $rest->handle();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about REST, but doesn't the usual `json_encode()` work?

```
// example: http://path/to/examples/StaticExample.php?method=sayHello&name=World
public static function sayHello($name)
{

    $myArray = array("Response" => "Hello, " . $name);
    return json_encode($myArray);
}
```

Comment: json_encode will work, however, PHP will only put the square brackets around the response if you have a multi-dimensional array.  Otherwise it will only use the curly brackets, which my ajax applications seem fine with.  Side note, I've never seen return work the way I want it to, in these cases, I've always had to use echo for my ajax call to pick it up.